# Some trouble with c code

Tags: c

When I choose push in my menu, then I enter some number value, then the program works fine, but when I enter some letter value, then program never stops, where is my mistake?
I'm beginner in c, so maybe someone can help solve this problem.
I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curses.h>

int a[15], top = -1;

void push (int value)
{
    if (top == 14)
    {
        printf("Stack is full");
    }
    else{
        top = top + 1;
        a[top] = value;
    }
}

void pop()
{
    if (top == -1)
    {
        printf("Stack is empty");
    }
    else
    {
        top = top - 1;
    }
}


void display()
{
    int i;
    if (top == -1)
    {
        printf("\n Nothing to display");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nArray is:\n");
        for (i=0; i<=top; i++)
        {
            printf("%d\n", a[i]);
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    int choice, value;
    do{
        printf("\n1.Push :");
        printf("\n2.POP :");
        printf("\n3.Display :");
        printf("\n4.Exit :");
        printf("\nEnter your Choice:");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        if(choice == 1)
        {
            printf("\nEnter Value to be inserted: ");
            scanf("%d", &value);
            push(value);
        }

        if(choice == 2)
        {
            pop();
        }

        if (choice == 3)
        {
            display();
        }

    }
    while (choice !=4);
    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your push function takes `int` value, why are you pushing a `char`

Comment: @MiteshPant in this line `void push (int value)` I change from int to char, but the same problem. In this part I need enter letter and number together, so I need char, write?

Comment: you need to cast input into char like `(char) input` and use char as the push param type

Comment: unrelated, but since each `choice` is mutually exclusive, you should change that to `if (choice == 1) { ... } elseif (choice == 2) { ... } elseif (choice == 3) { ... }`. No sense in checking choice against each of those conditions every time when it will only be one (or none) of those options

Comment: It is necessary to clear the input buffer when there is an illegal input. E.g `if(0 == scanf("%d", &var)){
   while(getchar()!='\n');
   input_NG = 1;
  }`

Answer (score 1):

You need to change two things for your code to work.First change the following variables to character

```
char a[15];
char value;
```

plus you also need to pass a charater to the function not an integer.